# How to decode the simplest xml with golang

Tags: xml, go

The xml is simple:

`<p>this is a test xml</p>`

and I tried many structs and cannot resolve it successfully.

Anyone knowns how to decode this?

Comment: Where is the xml code?

Comment: Sorry the code is rendered by html.  Code is like this: `<p>this is a test xml </p>`

Comment: Example: https://play.golang.org/p/9Qr5cTtQt6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolating your question (on [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/9Qr5cTtQt6)):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Dummy struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"p"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}

func main() {
    var dummy Dummy
    if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(`<p>this is a test xml</p>`), &dummy); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", dummy) // {{ p} this is a test xml}
}
```

Comment: Thank U, this resolve my question. But what if it is an array, like `<p>this is a test xml</p><p>this is another test xml</p>`? Thank you

Comment: @HuangTao Read the documentation for the [`encoding/xml` package's `Unmarshal` function](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal).